# Can´t see the inputs in dialog box- blender 2.93

Tags: python, scripting

i worked in a dialog box in blender 2.92 and it worked fine, but in this release the dialog box doesn´t show me the input, here an example:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
bl_info = {
     "blender" : (2, 93, 0),
     "location" : "View3D",
     "warning" : "",
     "category" : "Modifiers",
     }


import bpy
from bpy.props import *


class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
  bl_label = "Set object"
  bl_idname = "PT_TestPanel"
  bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
  bl_region_type = 'UI'
  bl_category = 'Set'      
  
  def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        split = layout.split()

        layout.operator('create.line_operator')
        
        # Create an row where the buttons are aligned to each other.
        #layout.label(text=" Set the object:")

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator("object1.simple_operator")
        
class PanelA(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_label = "Create spline"
  bl_idname = 'create.line_operator'
  
  spline = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "spline",default= False)
  
  def execute(self, context):
      s = self.spline
      bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
      bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
      bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')
      bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name = "builtin.draw")
      
      if s == True:
          bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.curve_paint_settings.depth_mode = 'SURFACE'              
      if s == False:                  
          bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.curve_paint_settings.depth_mode = 'CURSOR'
      return {'FINISHED'}
  
  def invoke(self, context,event):
      return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelA)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)   
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelA)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
   


#(i apreciated any help)
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with 2.93, non-annotation properties are no longer supported. In previous version it would output a (cryptic) warning in the console :

[image]

[See the related commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBafa5da9ce02bcd46f70d250943a933afe6de1d59)

The solution is to replace `=` by `:` in the property definition.

L.58 :

Replace

```
spline = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="spline", default=False)
```

With

```
spline: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="spline", default=False)
```

[Link to the related release notes (scroll to the bottom of the page)](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons)

Comment: Thanks man, you´ve helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!!!!!!