# 2.93 update throws error with bpy.props

Tags: python, add-on

Updating to 2.93 throws an error on a previously working script. Script:

```
text = bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter Hotkey", default= "" )
    
def execute(self, context):
    
    text = self.text
 
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES')
    obj = bpy.context.object
    obj.name = text
    if text == 'b':
        self.report({'INFO'}, "B Hotkey!")
    if text == 'r':
        self.report({'INFO'}, "R Hotkey!")
    
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
    return {'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    
    return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

And the resulting error:

```
obj.name = text
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: Object.name expected a string type, not _PropertyDeferred
```

I'm seeing an update in the 2.93 Release Notes that suggest something may be going on with bpy.props, but unable to make sense of it. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's supposed to be `text: bpy.props.StringProperty(...)` (with `:` not `=`), but don't know if that will fix it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224552/15543

Comment: Thanks to you both

Comment: Thank you @scurest ! Life saver!