# Unable to Access Registered Class Properties (Properties Grouped in Class)

Tags: python, interface, properties

I'm grouping my properties in a `class`
like this:

```py
class CTL_test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    variable = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Variable', description='', default='', subtype='NONE', maxlen=0)

bpy.utils.register_class(CTL_test)
bpy.types.Scene.ctl_test = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CTL_test)
```

After that if I access `bpy.context.scene.ctl_test.variable`,
This will give:
[image]

And, if I try to access, `Scene.ctl_test.bl_rna.properties['variable']`

```
AttributeError: 'CTL_test' object has no attribute 'variable'
```

Same, When I use this property in Interface, Like -

```py
row_5.prop(bpy.context.scene.ctl_test, 'variable', text='Name', icon_value=0, emboss=True)
```

This will give Error:

```
property not found: CTL_test.variable
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Problem is solved using,
`variable : bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Variable', description='', default='', subtype='NONE', maxlen=0)`
I think, class definition changed in new Python version.

Comment: can you please post it as an answer so we can close this thread :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can´t see the inputs in dialog box- blender 2.93](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224545/can%c2%b4t-see-the-inputs-in-dialog-box-blender-2-93)

Comment: Hi, Mohit ... glad you found a fix.. I'm going to close this as fixed without needing an answer. If you'd like to answer it yourself. please edit to re-open.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been self-answered in a comment.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hello, I want to answer my question (this may help others), But I'm unable to do, How can I answer?

Comment: @MohitSaini  Hi, Mohit .. re-opened for you .. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is Solved,

```py
class ClassName(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # Normal Data in Python Class
    label = 'My CTL Group'

    # Blender DataProperty in Python Class
    new_property: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='New Property')
```

And,
[image]

This Output Shows that `bpy.types.Scene.new_property` has registered successfully,
But `class` has not registered.

When, Both registers successfully, the output will look like this (default value)

[image]